# Why map task writes its output to disk in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I heard that map task persists its data onto disk. But this will make mapreduce slower especially for iterative algorithms.
Why do we want to persist the intermediate output to disk?
Why don't we directly send the output to the next phase without persisting the intermediate output to disk?

Comment: Durability is one reason. And not all data can fit in memory for large tasks

Comment: But if it can handle input split size, there is no way it won't handle the map task output. Adding to this, Apache Spark also computes in memory, which makes it 100x faster

Comment: Spark also defaults to spill to disk when the computation doesn't fit in memory. But Spark has other optimizations as well. In general, I don't find anyone actually writing mapreduce code in 5 years I've used Hadoop

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!! Actually i researched a bit and came to a conclusion. Your reply was valuable. :)